# how to load a local html file if there is no internet connection

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

I have a number of `uiwebview` in my app that display html files hosted on a server. I would also like to have local copies of the html files that will display if there is no internet connection, but I don't understand how to do that. The .m files I have are similar to below.

Currently the `uiwebview` will display the remotely hosted page (in the example below "contact.html". Is anyone able to explain how I can load a local copy of the file if there is no internet available?

```
#import "ContactMeViewController.h"
@interface ContactMeViewController ()
@end
@implementation ContactMeViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.domain.co.nz/apppages/contact.html";
    //Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    //URL Request Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webview loadRequest:requestObj];
webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
@end
```

I have updated the .m file as follows, but get a blank screen with no internet connection instead of the local file loading:

```
#import "ContactMeViewController.h"
@interface ContactMeViewController (UIWebViewDelegate)
@end
@implementation ContactMeViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.kuranimarsters.co.nz/apppages/contact.html";

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Request Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webview loadRequest:requestObj];
webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
}
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
if (-1009 == kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet) {
    // if we can identify the error i.e, no internet connection
    [self loadHtmlFile];
}
}
-(void)loadHtmlFile
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contact.html"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:content encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
@end
```

Comment: use delegate and when error comes, load local html page...

Comment: You can try https://github.com/rnapier/RNCachingURLProtocol

Answer (score 0):

Apply delegates for `UIWebView` and in `-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error` load local html file.

By default, if internet is there `-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`, will get executed and you will see page as per URL.

Answer (score 0):

you can store data of html file to document directory of app as.html file & load webview with this file on next time such as

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0],@"index.html"];   

// Download and write to file
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.co.nz/apppages/contact.html"];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

// Load file in UIWebView
 [web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];
```

Comment: hi poojathorat does that mean that effectively the app would download the remotely hosted pages and write to local files?

Comment: yes download the data of html page & write to document directory so that next time u could load from document directory only .

Answer (score 0):

Use delegate methods of webView and implement it in ContactMeViewController.m

In didFailLoadWithError method you can identify error code using [error code]. You can use kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet = -1009.

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if ([error code] == kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet) {
        // if we can identify the error i.e, no internet connection
        [self loadHtmlFile];
    }
}

-(void)loadHtmlFile
{
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"contact" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
}
```

Comment: Hi Tanuj, I have updated the code in the .m file (see the main question edit).
With the internet connection, the remote page loads fine, but without the internet connection, I am getting a blank page. Have I missed something?

Comment: i have done some changes in loadHtmlFile method. Please check again.

Comment: thanks for making the change, I have made the same change accordingly, but have the same issue, where there is a blank page if there is no internet connection

Comment: do you have the "contact.html" file inside your documentary file?

Comment: Hey I have the file in my project, I'm not sure if I know what you mean by documentary file - do i need to setup a file containing the html files within it?

Comment: yes you need to add "contact.html" file inside your project.

Comment: ok, yes I do have the file inside my project, but have the blank screen without Internet connection still

Comment: have you replaced your loadHtmlFile code with this:-(void)loadHtmlFile
{
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"contact" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
}

Comment: I did that just now, if I try to run and compile I get an error in -(void)loadHtmlFile saying "interface type cannot be statically allocated"

Comment: -(void)loadHtmlFile {
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"contact" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
}